# Sudo feature in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, sudo

I am using zsh on my Linux boxe as well as my MAC. However, in both env, I have a "problem".

When I type " !! ", it does not work in zsh, but does in bash. More, it's really useful with "sudo !!". How can I make it work with zsh ?. Do I need to alias something in my .zshrc ?

Comment: This question does not really relate to sudo. For future reference perhaps it is a good idea to reword it to something like history expansion or repeat previous command. (and remove the sudo tag)

Answer (score 2):

The `BANG_HIST` option is disabled for your `zsh`:

> **BANG_HIST** (**+K**) <C> <Z>
>
> Perform textual history expansion, **csh**-style, treating the character `**!**' specially.

This may happen through one of three methods:

1. By setting it explicitly with `set`/`setopt`. Somewhere in your shell configuration there is a line like one of these:

   ```
    setopt NO_BANG_HIST
    setopt -o NoBangHist
    setopt +o banghist
    set -o nobanghist
    set +o BANG_hist
   ```

   Case does not matter and `_` is ignored in the option name. `BANG_HIST` enables the feature and prepending `NO` (`NO_BANG_HIST`) disables the feature. `-o` sets the state of the feature as given by the name, `+o` inverts the meaning.
2. By starting `zsh` with the `-K` command line option:

   ```
   zsh -K
   ```

   You also can explicitly set it with `zsh +K` but that can be overridden with `setopt` in the configuration.
3. By starting `zsh` in emulation mode for either `sh` or `ksh`:

   ```
   ln -s /bin/zsh /usr/local/bin/ksh
   /usr/local/bin/ksh
   ```

   In that case the feature can also later be set with `setopt`, but not by command line option (`/usr/local/bin/ksh +K` does not work).

Answer (score 1):

**My zsh has `!!`**

I have installed zsh right now and `!!` works as it works in bash.

Maybe you need to update it?

My version is `5.0.2-3ubuntu6`

**But if your zsh doesn't have it:**

As answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165327/rerun-previous-command-under-sudo) you need to add this to your `.zshrc` file:

`alias ii='$(fc -ln -1)'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seem that I had a old "set opt" options in my .zshrc causing the problem.

I find out by testing each and every item in my .zshrc. Lucky me, it was not the last options.

I will test later what specific option I need to change or remove.

Regards